# Converting from String to array of Uint8 in Swift

Tags: string, swift, tokenize

I have a string of numbers that are separated by a zero like this "97 189 254 229 193 189 3" and I want to create an array where each entry is of the datatype UInt8 like this: [97, 189, 254, 229, 193, 189, 37, 51, 3].

I tried this

```
let TextInt = UInt8(TextString.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init))
```

where TextInt the array and TextString is the string, but I get the error *cannot invoke initializer for type 'UInt8' with an argument list of type '([String])'*

Comment: There are no zeros in that string. Do you mean separated by a space?

Answer (score 1):

### What about this?

```
let word = "97 189 254 229 193 189 3"

let nums = word.characters.split(" ").flatMap { UInt8(String($0)) }
```

### Notes

I am using `flatMap` because it automatically does discard the `nil` values. So if a *chunk* of the input string is something that cannot be converted into a `UInt8`, it's automatically discarded.

This also make possible having the type of `nums` to be `[UInt8]` and **not** `[UInt8?]`.